# Why does some transactions have an excessive number of receiving addresses?

Tags: transactions, address

Such as this transaction: 92088fe6b9d9c9db84d26481b80104f8ca566649a656b7aa3e67432b346cbf1c, which has over 5000 receiving addresses.

It is unlikely that someone would send money to that many business partners at once, let along each individual output is quite small. If that is done for privacy protection purpose, over 5000 receiving addresses is too excessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is unlikely that someone would send money to that many business
>   partners at once

Why? It's a mass payment for "shareholders". In this instance, the transaction you mentioned is a [known payment from a pool to their miners](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1338693.msg13656238#msg13656238).

Comment: With many of the payments under than one dollar?

Comment: Why not? The transaction you mentioned is known as a payment to miners from a pool https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1338693.msg13656238#msg13656238

Comment: Thank you. Are you aware of any way to find out which transaction is a payment to miners from a pool?

Comment: I've edited your post to add the comment's content to the answer, as the comment addressed the question more directly than the actual answer.

Comment: When I asked for specifically the transaction I mentioned, the field enough_fee is false. Is the fact that it is a mass payment from pool which allows the transaction to be confirmed despite the fact that there is no enough fees?

Comment: there is no "enough_fee" field in bitcoin transactions.

Comment: Miners select arbitrarily which transactions to confirm. If it was their own payout transaction, there is absolutely nothing stopping them from selecting their own transaction without paying a fee to themselves.

Comment: @amaclin Sorry for the late reply. The field is in the json returned by blocktrail.